# ActiveAdmin: Filter on method rather than attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, filter, activeadmin

I have a method on one of my models like the following:

```
def current?
  self.parent.start_date <= Time.zone.now.to_date && self.parent.end_date >= Time.zone.now.to_date && !self.archived
end
```

I'd like to create a simple filter in ActiveAdmin based on the result of this method (a simple select filter called `Current` with options `Yes`, `No`, and `Any`) but I can't seem to figure out how.

What's the best approach for filtering on a model method rather than one of its attributes?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the `conditions`. First thought is to use `scope`  but need to see the conditions to see if will work.

Comment: Also please specify what you are filtering is it records or views or method calls?

Comment: @tihom and engineersmnky - See update above.

Comment: what does `self.archived?` do?

Comment: @tihom `archived` is just a boolean field in that model's db schema.

Answer (score 0):

The following class method in the `ActiveAdmin.rb` would return all the records according to the conditions e.g. `ActiveAdmin.current("Yes")` or `ActiveAdmin.current("No")`.

```
def self.current(inp = "Yes") # default inp is "Yes"
  d = Time.zone.now.to_date
  return case inp
    # when inp == "Yes" it would return all the records with archived == false (won't return archived == nil) 
    # AND parents with start_date <= d and end_date >= d
    when "Yes" 
               where(archived: false ).
               joins(:parent).
               where("parents.start_date <= ? AND parents.end_date >= ?",d,d)

    # when inp == "No" it would return all the records with archived == true (won't return archived == nil)
    # AND parents with start_date > d OR end_date < d
    when "No"  
               where(archived: true ).
               joins(:parent).
               where("parents.start_date > ? OR parents.end_date < ?",d,d)

    # when inp = "Any" return all records
    when "Any"
               scoped 

    # return all records if inp does not match any of the above options
    else
               scoped
    end

end
```

Comment: Sorry, where does this go? The ActiveAdmin.register block for my model? And what would the 'filter' method look like? Thanks for your help.

Comment: this goes in the `ActiveAdmin.rb` file. It allows you to access the filtered records by calling `ActiveAdmin.current`. `ActiveAdmin` is a model in your app right?

Comment: No, ActiveAdmin is a gem I'm using in my project (https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin).